# Cost of assigning to array

Tags: arrays, performance

I have a program that looks like this:

```
int i;

double* a = new double [2];

for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
{
    a[0] = 1.1231;
    a[0] = 1.1231;
    a[0] = 1.1231;
    ..
}
```

The line a[0] = 1.1231; has been copied manually 10.000 times, hence the command is called 10.000.000.000 times. This takes 8.7 seconds to run. However, if I run the loop 10.000.000 times and copy the statement manually 1.000 times (aka same number of array assignments, just different layout), I get a runtime of 3 seconds. How can this be? I am compiling with -O0. Is there something else I need to do to disable compiler optimization? I am asking because I am optimizing a program and I am comparing performance of different containers...

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you disable optimizations when testing performance?

Comment: There is nothing strange here. This technique is called loop unrolling, normally an optimizing compiler can do it

Comment: I think he is trying to determine on his own which is fastest, without optimization.

Comment: do you really have ten thousand actual lines, or is it a nested for loop?

Comment: But why do both programs have different runtimes ...?

Comment: I have 10.000 actual lines

Comment: Because you made an optimization in one: loop unrolling

Comment: Why don't you look at the assembly?

Comment: I would like know, for the future, when calculating runtimes of programs, who much I should bencil in for an array assignment. I am comparing this to std::vector assignments for example.

Comment: Whats "the assembly"? Is that the machine code? Also, the unrolled actually takes me longer to run.

Comment: Please tell me size of your binaries. Cache effects IMO.

Comment: The object file is 480 KB for the more compact version and 660 KB for the one with more text lines

Comment: You say that you want to know how long the assignment takes for future calculation of running times--I think you'll just be more confused with that approach. There's really no way to know how a program performs except to time it after it's done. The number of things that affect performance is large and complex: different systems have different timings for similar instructions, branch prediction, cache locality, memory alignment, available memory at runtime, and so on.  Even the compiler's optimizer can't know everything it wants to know like your program's typical input values.

Comment: So the loop probably takes 20/200 KB. I guess 20KB fits instruction cache of your processor and 200KB does not so processor has to reload code in each iteration.